# How to Fetch changes in git repository in XCode 4?

Tags: git, xcode4, fetch

I have just downloaded a code from github and now would like to "Fetch" the changes on the gitbub into my local repo, how I can do that within xcode 4? Or I have to do it manually by going to command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu File / Source Control / Pull…

Comment: Got that... Actually previously I was in wrong brach... In master brach it work great... Thanks.

Comment: how can you do a Git Fetch Origin within XCode?